# require_once failed in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing for first time a WordPress plugin. I have two .php (**file1.php**, **file2.php**). In **file1.php** I have defined a form with a action to **file2.php** for upload images. In **file2.php** I just do a

```
require_once('./wp-admin/includes/file.php');
```

but I receive this error

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file2.php

I tried with `require_once()`, `include()`, with the entire route, etc. I reviewed permissions, routes and it's correct. I tried the `require_once()` in **file1.php** and it works but I need it in **file2.php**.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Deploying the logs:

`require_once('./wp-admin/includes/file.php');`

Warning: require_once(./wp-admin/includes/file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file2.php on line 15

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-admin/includes/file.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file2.php on line 15

```
require_once('/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 16

This error is to a WordPress function, so I suppose that it is not the error, it will be another but....

Comment: 500 is hiding some other error, check logs

Comment: @Dagon Yes, sorry. I received this error Warning: require_once(./wp-admin/includes/file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file2.php on line 6

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-admin/includes/file.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file2.php on line 6 but it exists, in the same directory and it has permissions so I don't understand the error.

Comment: well that error seems clear

Comment: @Dagon maybe not because if I comment that require, the error doesn't appear. I think it is a route error but I said that I tried several routes and nothing. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Seems Your require path is incorrect... Check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116366/what-is-the-right-way-to-include-a-wp-admin-file-in-your-theme

Comment: @DpĚN Thx, I've checked several articles, post, etc and my problem persist since 2 days xD so something strange does the .php so I posted here :(

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew Thank you, that was the solution.

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew done, but I can't vote yet. I have not enough reputacion :(

Comment: Oh right :) well, some day